# pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf() fails on dtypes object

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pathlib

I'm trying to export a pandas DataFrame to a hdf5-file. The DataFrame having the following structure.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       4 non-null      float64
 1   b       4 non-null      float64
 2   c       4 non-null      float64
 3   d       4 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes
```

Within column d I do store some file paths as type.
`<class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>`

If I call the to_hdf() function like this
`df.to_hdf(r'C:\data\test.h5', mode='w', key=key,format='table', data_columns=True)`
I will get the following error.

```
File "C:\py36_4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4800, in _maybe_convert_for_string_atom
    for i in range(len(block.shape[0])):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

If I would skip the column d the export to hdf5 is working as expected. So therefore it seems to be an issue of column d and the used type '`<class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>`'?

**Update to my Question:**

The following code will reproduce this issue.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['test1','test2'],'b':[1.1,2.1]})
df1.to_hdf('test1.h5', key='test1', format='table', data_columns=True)
    
df2=pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[1,:]).transpose()
df2.to_hdf('test2.h5', key='test2', format='table', data_columns=True)
```

I looks like that the issue comes from the transpose() function. This will change the `dtype` of all columns to `object` and the hdf5 export will fail for `df2`. This seems also only to be happen if one column of the DataFrame `df1` is of this type.

Comment: I did some further testing. If I convert column d to a string the export is working. df.d=df.d.astype(str). So the type <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'> is not supported within hdf5 export.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm your observation. The latest versions of pandas and tables are now supporting the serialization of pathlib Path's. Maybe you should

```
pip install --upgrade pandas tables
```

Comment: I'm sorry i missed this information. Python 3.6.4, pandas 1.0.3, tables  3.6.1. So I think my environment is up to date? Which was  confirmed by running your pip command.

Comment: Okay, but then you should share your DataFrame() constructor, so that this error gets reproducible. I had no issues with storing a Path column in hdf.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my late response. I did an update to my question where you might be able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case, my problem was that I had a column named `0` (created by the fact that I had a numpy array with dictonaries instead of a list with dictionaries when calling `pd.DataFrame`).

Renaming the column solved all issues.

Comment: Thanks for your idea but I think it is somehow different in my case. I added an update to my question to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved the problem by using the infer_objects() function pointed out here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dtypes

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['test1','test2'],'b':[1.1,2.1]})   
df2=pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[1,:]).transpose()
df2 = df2.infer_objects()
df2.to_hdf('test2.h5', key='test2', format='table', data_columns=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug of the pandas.

ref [38919](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/38919)

by now, you should not use int as column name, use string for example